# sorting vector of vectors

Tags: c++, stl

I understand there are a couple of questions already and I believe I tried all the solutions suggested but still running into issues . My inner vector is the row with size 3 I nee to sort the outer vector based on column 0 which is first element of each row in the vector  and then 1 ,2 subsequently.

#### Code:

```
vector < vector<double> > ftstPrices;

for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    vector <double> stepPrices;

    for (j=0 ;j<1259;j++)
    {
        stepPrices.push_back(.......);
    }//end of for price simu

    stepPrices.erase(stepPrices.begin(),stepPrices.begin()+251);
    stepPrices.erase(stepPrices.begin()+1,stepPrices.begin()+252);
    stepPrices.erase(stepPrices.begin()+2,stepPrices.begin()+757);
    ftstPrices.push_back(stepPrices);//push the inner vector into outer

    /* this is the tricky part im having issues with */
    sort(ftstPrices.begin(),ftstPrices.end(), [](const vector<double>&x,const vector<double>&y) {
            return stepPrices[0]<stepPrices[0]
            });
}
```

#### Errors:

```
C:\CPP\Projects\monteCarlo\simulations.cpp|68|error: 'stepPrices' is not captured|
C:\CPP\Projects\monteCarlo\simulations.cpp|68|error: 'stepPrices' is not captured|
C:\CPP\Projects\monteCarlo\simulations.cpp|68|error: expected ';' before '}' token|
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h||In instantiation of 'void
```

Example Input and out put as requested 
     column1  column2  column3

```
 83.0201  13.3513  24.56
 15.8398  43.3559  9.66
 28.9211  38.8552  32.33
 22.8481  45.9503  8.45
 6.20375  16.6046  11.95
```

StepPrices are the rows which are are added to the ftstPrices vector

After sorting the vector should look like this
     column1    Column2  Column3

```
 6.20375  13.3513  8.45
 15.8398  16.6046  9.66
 22.8481  38.8552  11.95
 28.9211  43.3559  24.56
 83.0201  45.9503  32.33
```

Comment: Read your lambda again.

Comment: aah the dreaded down vote lol ,Im reaching out because I could not figure out.

Comment: @sree Like pointed out, you probably didn't mean to do `return stepPrices[0]<stepPrices[0]`.

Comment: In other words, you have an 2D table represented as a vector of *rows* but you want to sort the individual *columns*?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't represent the table as a vector of columns instead?

Comment: @T.C. hmm that would be a little bit odd...ok this what Im doing . Im creating a million paths for each stock price in the s&p index so each price path for the stock is a row and since its the s&p index will have to do this for 500 stocks .To answer your question it would be really hard to visualize

Comment: Put `stepPrices` inside the square brackets of your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).

What we need is a random access range (for `sort()`) whose elements each map to a single element inside the corresponding element of the original range. So we can write a transformation functor:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct select_element
{
    template<class T>    
    typename T::reference operator()(T& source) const { return source[N]; }
};
```

Note that `operator ()` returns a reference to the container's `value_type`, to enable modifications.

Now we can use it with the `transformed` range adaptor:

```
using boost::adaptors::transformed;

std::vector<std::vector<double>> input = /* ... */;

boost::sort(input | transformed(select_element<0>()));
boost::sort(input | transformed(select_element<1>()));
boost::sort(input | transformed(select_element<2>()));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c76d596f1c2e3194).

If you can't use Boost, the conceptually simplest way would be to gather each column into separate vectors, sort the columns, and then regenerate the rows from the sorted columns.

Comment: thank you for the boost tip , yes I would like to try that. I would not want to create another vector and sort it as I have a million rows and the will have to do this for each of the 500 items I need to generate this for

Answer (score 0):

You can use the good old `std::sort()`, defining a comparator:

```
struct DataRowComparatorByColumnIndex {
  bool operator() ( const std::vector<double>& row1,
                    const std::vector<double>& row2 ) {
      return row1[m_columnIndex] < row2[m_columnIndex] ;
  }
  uint m_columnIndex;
};
```

Then use it to sort your table/dataframe/matrix:

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > table = /* ... */;

// Sort the data by given column.
DataRowComparatorByColumnIndex dataRowComparatorByColumnIndex;
dataRowComparatorByColumnIndex.m_columnIndex = 2; //sort by 3rd column
std::sort( result.begin(), result.end(), dataRowComparatorByColumnIndex );
```